# OSI Model: SSH vs HTTP

Tags: tcp, ssh, communication, osi

I wonder, why SSH is in the Session Layer of Model OSI, but HTTP is in the Application Layer?
as I see it, both are working over TCP/IP communication so why discriminate the two protocols to two different layers?

Comment: you can tunnel multiple protocols, including HTTP, through SSH, thus logically it should be lower in the stack. BTW not sure if this is not OT here.

Comment: It isn't. SSH is an application layer otocol just like HTTP. Your question is founded on a false premise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP does not care what way it is sent, it simly consists of text, which can then be parsed by an application "speaking" HTTP, whereas SSH creates a "virtal connection" (session) over an existing network and allows higher-level protocolls (like HTTP) to pass more securely

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.